# .htaccess rewrite frustrations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I made my website in PHP originally and used parameters for page/product identification.

```
ex.) http://mysite.com/?pid=my_products&sid=golf_clubs&GTIN=111111111111
```

I've now moved over to using RoR and I'd like to set up redirects to clean up the urls

```
http://mysite.com/my_products/golf_clubs/111111111111
```

I've looked at tutorials and arrived at this:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ ?pid=$1&sid=$2&GTIN=$3 [NC]
```

I've tested a url and it doesn't redirect at all.  I've tried putting this in the .htaccess file to debug and chmodded the log folder to 775 but I get a 500 error:

```
RewriteLog "/home/myaccount/rails_apps/myapp/log/rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 3
```

As far as rewrite statements in .htaccess goes, this is what I have:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteLog "/home/myaccount/rails_apps/myapp/log/rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 3
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/downloads.*
RewriteRule .* - [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ pid=$1&sid=$2&GTIN=$3 [NC]

RewriteRule ^$ index.html [QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.html [QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ dispatch.fcgi [QSA,L]

ErrorDocument 500 "<h2>Application error</h2>Rails application failed to start properly"
```

*** I am on a shared hosting plan with Bluehost (good gawd I wish they'd update to Rails 3 soon)

Comment: As I understand you want to **redirect** from OLD style URL `http://mysite.com/?pid=my_products&sid=golf_clubs&GTIN=111111111111` to a new style `http://mysite.com/my_products/golf_clubs/111111111111` ? If so -- then your rules are doing other way around unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you have your rule backwards. You want to catch your old URLs and rewrite them to the new format, correct? In that case, you want this:

```
RewriteRule ^\?pid=(\w+)\&sid=(\w+)\&GTIN=(\w+) /$1/$2/$3 [NC,R=301,L]
```

Adding a 301 status will tell the user agent (including well-behaved search bots) that your canonical URLs have permanently changed.

Comment: This will not work -- `RewriteRule` does NOT work with query string that way -- try `RewriteCond` instead.

Comment: After considering both your comments, it's at the point where it redirecting but adding a double slash "//" when there isn't the presence of the 2nd and 3rd parameter.  RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^pid=(\w+)(?:\&sid=(\w+))?(?:\&GTIN=(\w+))?
RewriteRule ^$ %1/%2/%3 [NC,R=301,L]

Comment: @Jake In this case (when some parameters are missing) create 3 separate rules for 3, 2 and 1 parameter only in that order. Otherwise you will have to issue redirect in your RoR application because I don't know a way how you can insert default value when parameter is missing.

Comment: @Jake I'm not sure at all if this is going to work (and I have no Apache around right now to test it), but try this: `RewriteRule ^$ %1(?%2/)%2(?%3/)%3 [NC,R=301,L]` -- I saw this used for Apache-alike rewrite module -- it should insert slash ONLY if 2nd/3rd parameter is present